# Using Components and a shared instance of a view model in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

I've recently started learning HTML/JS and more specifically KnockoutJS. 
One of the concepts I am struggling to understand is components and how you deal with viewmodels. Here the an example of what I am running into and unsure of the correct way of approaching this.

I've got a a viewmodel that I want to act like a re-usable widget. I'll call it widget.viewmodel.js. I've also got another viewmodel that is the overall page, so I'll call that page.viewmodel.js. And of course a template for the widget which I'll refer to as widgetTemplate.ko.html.

So what I am attempting to do is that inside of page.viewmodel.js, I want to create a widget.viewmodel.js for which to keep a reference to as I plan on adding subscribers to the the reference to handle changes that need to be reflected on the page.viewmodel.js.

so for page.viewmodel.js I have

```
var widget = new WidgetViewModel(params);
var component = "widget-component";
if(!ko.components.isRegistered(component)){
    ko.components.register(component, {viewModel: widget, template: widgetTemplate.ko.html});
}

var container= $("<div/>").attr("data-bind", 'component: {name" + component + '"});
ko.applyBinding(widget, container[0]); //issue here saying that widget is not a view model

this.append(container);
```

So there a couple concerns here. First, its doesn't work because it complains that the applyBinding that it is expecting a viewmodel.

Secondly, I am complete unsure if the structure here makes any sense. I attempted to read through the KO tutorials, but I am failing to understand them.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Definitely read http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html
You don't use `applyBindings` to bind a component. You register it with its viewmodel constructor function, which receives parameters at binding time (from the `data-bind` in the HTML).

Comment: You shouldn't have to apply bindings directly to the widget like that, you're registering the component to the ko object on the page, so when you apply bindings it'll create widgets as it sees them.  check out: http://jsfiddle.net/timh06/nf6dgzpo/

Comment: You really don't want to couple it so tightly like that.  Use message passing to communicate between view models. Something like [postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) will help facilitate that.

Comment: @Timh In this case you are including the values for the widgets in the HTML. However, I have the case in which this needs to be populated dynamically. How would you suggest going about implementing this pattern? Thanks!

Comment: I'm imagining your use case as a button on the page that adds a new widget or something like that.  In that case, why not use knockout *only* to handle the DOM stuff -- http://jsfiddle.net/8Ldw57oq/2/, foregoing the component.
This won't work if the widget markup is dynamic, but that isn't apparent in your example (i.e. `widgetTemplate.ko.html`).  I'd say use *foreach* or *with* to help with sub-viewmodels when it's a simple use case.